# What does it mean that a type is "bridged"

Tags: swift

In "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.6 beta)" by Apple, in the Language Reference/Statements section, there is a formal definition of a guard statement

```
guard <condition> else {
  <statements>
}
```

where, I quote *“...The value of any condition in a guard statement must be of type Bool or a type bridged to Bool.  The condition can also be an optional binding declaration, as discussed in Optional Binding...”*

What does it mean for a type to `be bridged to Bool` (or to whatever other type `T` assuming bridging to `T` is possible)?  Is this something specific to `Bool`, like an implicit cast?  Is it a built-in or can one generally bridge to any `T` by following a formal procedure.

I've searched far and wide but have not been able to find a formal-ish description of bridging in the same publication or elsewhere (if one exists please point it out to me).

Comment: "Bridged" here means "substitutable by saying `as`". This is a way of crossing the boundary between languages, namely Swift <-> C/Objective-C. For example, String is bridged to NSString. It's hard to think of a type bridged to Bool other than CBool, which is the C language `bool` type.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But that note in the docs is misleading, as ObjCBool is not bridged to Bool.

Comment: I think that the docs are compiled to cover not only existing cases, but also cases that could possibly exist. That is although now there's nothing (known to me) that can be used as "as Bool", docs should cover the case if such types will be added to the standard library at some point later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "bridging" for Swift comes from the older Cocoa frameworks concept of [Toll-Free Bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html). In Objective-C, certain Foundation class types have the same underlying layout as their CoreFoundation counterpart types such that it's possible to cast between one type and another and have them work identically: you can create a CoreFoundation object in C, then pass it to Objective-C and call methods on it — or you can create a Foundation object in Objective-C, and pass that object to a function in C expecting the CoreFoundation equivalent. Toll-Free Bridging allows you to cross the "bridge" between languages/levels of abstraction, without paying a "toll" to convert between the types (since the cast is direct in memory, there's  no runtime cost to converting these types).

Not all types are like this, and these types are designed specifically to behave in this way.

The concept was carried over to Swift, where certain Foundation types can be similarly "bridged" to Swift types, such as `String` ↔︎ `NSString`, `Array` ↔︎ `NSArray`, `Dictionary` ↔︎ `NSDictionary`, etc. The bridging isn't necessarily *always* "toll-free" (as in, the objects can be cast directly in memory without their underlying representation being changed), but close enough.

The statement, then, saying

> The value of the *condition* must be of type `Bool` or a type bridged to `Bool`.

means that the condition must be a `Bool`, or a type which can be converted directly into a `Bool` in this way.

The tricky thing about this description is that there isn't a type which can be unconditionally bridged into a `Bool` from Objective-C anymore. You can bridge an `NSNumber` to a `Bool` with a conditional cast (e.g. `let b = NSNumber(value: true) as? Bool`), but that's not enough to allow you to substitute an `NSNumber` in place of the condition:

```swift
while NSNumber(value: true) as? Bool { // error: Value of type 'Bool?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Bool'
    print("Hello")
}
```

I believe this sentence is a holdover from previous versions of the language where the rules are a little bit different — and is sort of confusing now.

---

> Is it a built-in or can one generally bridge to any T by following a formal procedure.

- If you know that a type `T` bridges to a type `U` unconditionally (e.g., `Array` ↔︎ `NSArray`, or `String` ↔︎ `NSString`), you can bridge between them with an `as` cast: `let a1: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]; let a2 = a1 as NSArray`, or `let s1: NSString = "Hello"; let s2 = s1 as String`)
- If you know that a type `T` bridges to a type `U` conditionally (e.g., `NSNumber` ↔︎ `Bool` above, since not all numbers can be converted to a `Bool`), the same can be done with an `as?` cast

Otherwise, bridging is a feature that's you can't meaningfully opt into outside of the compiler, standard library, and Apple frameworks. The Swift standard library has an underscored [`_ObjectiveCBridgeable`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d39782172d91c9c6854389c48d4929a1baa31100/stdlib/public/core/BridgeObjectiveC.swift#L18) that Foundation uses to add bridging implementations (e.g., [bridging `Array` ↔︎ `NSArray`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/3d1c1ad39b69aa994b52671209936e81ab28b6fd/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/NSArray.swift#L27), or e.g., [bridging `UUID` ↔︎ `NSUUID`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/eec4b26deee34edb7664ddd9c1222492a399d122/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/UUID.swift#L20)), but a lot of bridging mechanisms are also built into the compiler.